# Is it really necessary to specify serializer class when the serializer is called explicitly?

Tags: django-rest-framework

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) for generic views gives the following example (comments are mine):

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer # Is this line necessary?
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True) # Explicit call
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here, `UserSerializer` is called explicitly in the `list` method. So, do I need to specify the `serializer_class`? It seems to work without the specification, but I want to make sure that I am not doing anything bad by removing that line.

In my case, this question is somewhat more important, because I have a serializer that is used *only* in `list` and hence I define it inside `list`, so that it is out of scope in the surrounding class context.

Comment: everything is good. you only lose some minor things, like doc generating features. also if you are overriding `list` like that it is better to use `generics.GenericAPIView`

Comment: I use `generics.ListAPIView`. In what sense is `generics.GenericAPIView` better?

Comment: `generics.ListAPIView` is just `generics.GenericAPIView` with the list mixin https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L193. and you are overriding the `list` function. and not using its functionality.

Comment: @EhsanNouri I see. But wait, isn't this what the above example taken from the documentation is doing as well?